# Using tapply to calculate the mean based on column name

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks ike this:

```
   sample_id       target_id     tpm
1 SRR3884840X           (A)n     0.00000
2 SRR3884840X           (AC)n    0.00000
3 SRR3884840X           (AG)n    0.00000
4 SRR3884840X           (AT)n    15.54990
5 SRR3884840X           (C)n     3.10997
6 SRR3884840X           (CAA)n   6.21995
27357  SRR3884841X      (A)n     0.00000e+00
27358  SRR3884841X      (AC)n    0.00000e+00
27359  SRR3884841X      (AG)n    0.00000e+00
27360  SRR3884841X      (AT)n    0.00000e+00
27361  SRR3884841X      (C)n 1.  76941e+01
27362  SRR3884841X      (CAA)n 3.53882e+01
1094236 SRR3884878C comp78901_c0_seq3_1      916                
1094237 SRR3884878C comp85230_c0_seq1_1      1002                  
1094238 SRR3884878C comp56944_c0_seq1_1      2285              

example data:
> dput(droplevels(head(teX,15)))
structure(list(sample_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "SRR3884840X", class
"factor"), 
target_id = structure(1:15, .Label = c("(A)n", "(AC)n", "(AG)n", 
"(AT)n", "(C)n", "(CAA)n", "(CAAA)n", "(CAAAA)n", "(CAAAAA)n", 
"(CCA)n", "(CCCCA)n", "(CCCCAA)n", "(CCCCCA)n", "(CCCGAA)n", 
"(CCCTAA)n"), class = "factor"), tpm = c(0, 0, 0, 15.5499, 
3.10997, 6.21995, 43.5396, 9.32992, 3.10997, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), .Names = c("sample_id", "target_id", "tpm"), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to calculate the average tpm for each target_id (~12000 target_id across 10 sample_id) so I used lapply:

```
teXmean <- tapply(teX$target_id , teX$tpm, mean)
```

This returns an array that looks like this:

```
   0 2.25378e-10 3.21558e-10 4.49778e-10  4.5942e-10 4.63221e-10  5.5716e-10 5.63276e-10 5.90753e-10 6.20478e-10 
     NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

Is there a way to recover the target_id for each average or am I completely on the wrong path here? The end goal would be to calculate the average for each target_id, remove the entries that have a target_id containing the string "comp" and then generate a heatmap using heatmap.2.

Comment: You have a typo. Try reversing the arguments: `tapply(teX$tpm, teX$target_id, mean)` or explicitly provide the argument names `tapply(INDEX=teX$target_id , X=teX$tpm, FUN=mean)`.

Comment: whelp. That fixed it.

Comment: Also note that `mean` will return `NA` if there are any missing values, so in the future you could be more explicit and say `tapply(teX$tpm, teX$target_id, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: @MarkWhite it is simpler to write `tapply(teX$tpm, teX$target_id, mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @HubertL good call—I could have sworn that that hadn't worked for me various times before.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dplyr` :

```r
tab <- structure(list(sample_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "SRR3884840X", class ="factor"), 
               target_id = structure(1:15, .Label = c("(A)n", "(AC)n", "(AG)n", 
                                                      "(AT)n", "(C)n", "(CAA)n", "(CAAA)n", "(CAAAA)n", "(CAAAAA)n", 
                                                      "(CCA)n", "(CCCCA)n", "(CCCCAA)n", "(CCCCCA)n", "(CCCGAA)n", 
                                                      "(CCCTAA)n"), class = "factor"), 
               tpm = c(0, 0, 0, 15.5499, 3.10997, 6.21995, 43.5396, 9.32992, 3.10997, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
               .Names = c("sample_id", "target_id", "tpm"), 
               row.names = c(NA, 15L),
               class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
tab %>%
  group_by(target_id) %>%
  summarise(mean_tpm = mean(tpm))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 2
#>    target_id mean_tpm
#>       <fctr>    <dbl>
#>  1      (A)n  0.00000
#>  2     (AC)n  0.00000
#>  3     (AG)n  0.00000
#>  4     (AT)n 15.54990
#>  5      (C)n  3.10997
#>  6    (CAA)n  6.21995
#>  7   (CAAA)n 43.53960
#>  8  (CAAAA)n  9.32992
#>  9 (CAAAAA)n  3.10997
#> 10    (CCA)n  0.00000
#> 11  (CCCCA)n  0.00000
#> 12 (CCCCAA)n  0.00000
#> 13 (CCCCCA)n  0.00000
#> 14 (CCCGAA)n  0.00000
#> 15 (CCCTAA)n  0.00000
```